# How to make spring managed classes in method signature optional?

Tags: java, spring

How can I define a spring managed method signature where the injected service is optional?

The following does of course not work as the `@Autowired` annotation is not allowed inside the method signature. But that's what my intention is.

```
@Bean
public MyService myService(@Autowired(required = false) OptionalService optional) {
     MyService service = new MyService();
     //configure service if optional service is supplied
     return service; 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use @Bean with method but instead declare your class `MyService` with `@Service` and have it scanned with your Spring configuration. Then you can have a field of type `OptionalService` with `@Autowired(required = false)`.
Your service should look like this :

```
@Service
public class Myservice {

  @Autowired(required=false)
  private OptionalService optional;

}
```

Then if you need to do something after your optionalService has been injected by Spring (or not as it's not required), you can have your service implements `InitializingBean` and its `afterPropertiesSet` method and do it here.